# How to add a Keyword to YouTube Video Title

Tags: video, youtube, addition, title, keyword

I have a YouTube Module that scrape videos from some youtube users account daily.
I want to know, how to I add an extra Keyword to the YouTube Video Title?

Original Title: Jon Michael - Video

I want to change the Title to - Jon Michael - Video - Hot Clip

This is the scripts module I'm using to get YouTube videos in to my website.

error_reporting(0);
$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/'.$username.'/uploads?orderby=published&start-index=1&max-results=50';

```
$sxml = @simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
//print_r($sxml);
if($sxml)
    {
    // get summary counts from opensearch: namespace
    $counts = $sxml->children('http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/');

    echo "Total Videos=".$counts."<br/>";

    $_SESSION['total'] = ceil($counts->totalResults);
    $i='0';
    $_SESSION['page'] = 1;
    // iterate over entries in feed
    foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {

        // get nodes in media: namespace for media information
        $media = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');

        // get video player URL
        $attrs = $media->group->player->attributes();
        $watch = $attrs['url']; 

        // get video thumbnail
        $attrs = $media->group->thumbnail[0]->attributes();
        $thumbnail = $attrs['url']; 

        // get <yt:duration> node for video length
        $yt = $media->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
        $attrs = $yt->duration->attributes();
        $length = $attrs['seconds']; 

        // get <yt:stats> node for viewer statistics
        $yt = $entry->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
        $attrs = $yt->statistics->attributes();
        $viewCount = @$attrs['viewCount']; 

        // get <gd:rating> node for video ratings
        $gd = $entry->children('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'); 
        if ($gd->rating) {
            $attrs = $gd->rating->attributes();
            $rating = $attrs['average']; 
        } else {
            $rating = 0; 
        } 

        $published = (string)$entry->published;
        $publishedDate = strtotime($published);

        $arr[] = array(
                        'title' => addslashes((string)$media->group->title),
                        'description' => addslashes((string)$media->group->description),
                        'url' => (string)$watch,
                        'thumbnail' => (string)$thumbnail,
                        'duration' => (string)$length,
                        'views' => (string)$viewCount,
                        'rating' => (string)$rating,
                        'published' => $publishedDate
                    );  
        $i++;
    }
}


foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
    {
    $title=$val[title];
    $description=$val[description];
    $thumb=$val[thumbnail];
    $duration=$val[duration];
    $views=$val[views];
    $rating=$val[rating];
    $publish=$val[published];

    $url2=$val[url];
    $urlexp=explode('&',$url2);
    $url=$urlexp[0];

    $urlexp=explode('?v=',$url);
    $youtube_key=$urlexp[1];

    $tags=$title;

    echo '<b>Title</b>='.$title;
    echo '<br/><b>Description</b>='.$description;
    echo '<br/><b>Url</b>='.$url;
    echo '<br/><b>Thumb</b>='.$thumb;
    echo '<br/><b>Duration</b>='.$duration;
    echo '<br/><b>Views</b>='.$views;
    echo '<br/><b>Rating</b>='.$rating;
    echo '<br/><b>Publish</b>='.$publish;

    $er="select VIDEOID from videos where youtube_key='".$youtube_key."'";

    $chkExist=mysql_query($er) or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($chkExist)=='0')
        {
        $date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime(now));

        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO videos(USERID,title,description,tags,categories,filesize,time_added,date_added,featured,viewcount,runtime,public,rating,allowcomments,allowratings,allowembeds,allowdownloads,active,mature,youtube_embed,youtube_key) values('4','".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($description)."','".$tags."','".$cat."','0','".strtotime(now)."','".$date."','1','".mysql_real_escape_string($views)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($duration)."','1','".mysql_real_escape_string($rating)."','1','1','1','1','1','0','1','".mysql_real_escape_string($youtube_key)."')");
        $videoid = mysql_insert_id();
        $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE videos SET video_name='".$videoid.".flv' WHERE VIDEOID ='".$videoid."'");

        $thumbname=$videoid.'-1.jpg';
        $thumbname2=$videoid.'-2.jpg';
        $thumbname3=$videoid.'-3.jpg';

        $thumb1='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/'.$youtube_key.'/1.jpg';
        $thumb2='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/'.$youtube_key.'/2.jpg';
        $thumb3='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/'.$youtube_key.'/3.jpg';;

        copy($thumb1,'images/videothumbs/'.$thumbname);
        copy($thumb2,'images/videothumbs/'.$thumbname2);
        copy($thumb3,'images/videothumbs/'.$thumbname3);
        }
    elseif(mysql_num_rows($chkExist))   
        {
        echo 'Already Exists';
        }
    echo '<br/><br/><hr size="1"/>';

    }
```

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. I'm not sure how you want to add this keyword and if this keyword is dynamic or not.
Because is possible so, but I doubt that this is the answer you want: `$title=$val[title].' - Hot Clip';`

Comment: Smartik, thanks for reply.

The Keyword is going be Static. I want to add " - Hot Clip" at the end of each video is scrape. Thanks for your help friend.

Comment: So, isn't the solution from my comment above? Just to replace first variable from `foreach`.

Comment: :) Nice. Glad that it works.

Comment: @Smartik,

Using the same method, I want to add Keyword Tags (same tags) How do I add then with Space in between?

Thanks man! This will help me a lot.